# Current navigation levles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation, current-navigation

I am struggling with some SharePoint 2013 navigation structure. What I need is something like this below. That is, a navigation in the left side with three levels, that expands. I think that this should or could be solved with some Subsites instead of pages, but I am not able to hit the right structure.

Do anybody have some ideas, or advices on how to proceed? It has to be out of the box, or should it be coded, it has to be a minimum amount of developing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to be looking into the 'Managed Navigation' features of SharePoint.

This is not enabled by default and is dependent on the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature being enabled the site collection level.

You will then need to create a Managed Navigation term set to store your navigation labels and their respective targets, which can be pages within the current site, or subsites.

Comment: I have lokked into Managed Navigation, but is it possible to have it like "fold-out". So I always can see Level1, even if level 2 and 3 is folded out.